# WPF Font Awesome not working with Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, caliburn

With `caliburn.micro` I can't access to any third-party fonts in my folder in my WPF Solution, and I was able to ensure the following:

- Build Action is set to Resources
- Font family = `"./Font/#FontAwesome"`

And I still cannot retrieve icons from Font Awesome.

The XAML code from my button:

```
<Button Name="MailButton"               
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
        Width="60" Height="60" 
        Content="&#xf101;" 
        FontSize="30" 
        Foreground="White" 
        BorderThickness="0"  
        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" 
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
        FontFamily="./Font/#FontAwesome"
        Background="#FF085078"/>
```

In my second project without using the Caliburn font, it worked, even when I tried to access it in the same way as I did in my first project. What can I do more to make this font working? What properties of my project should I check first?

Comment: I'm glad you've figured out the problem yourself! However, please provide your solution as a separate post (answer) to the question, and not as an edit.

Comment: Thanks for advice @Jerrybibo ! Can you prove my answer please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the leading period (`.`) from the font family path, then you can access your font. Example:

```
FontFamily = "/Font/#FontAwesome"
```